# How do I express binary literals in Two's Complement in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, binary, literals, twos-complement

In python, 0b01001011 would be 75, which also works in Two's Complement. But 0b10101001 would be 169, where as in with Two's Complement it would be -87. How do I express Two's Complement binary literals?

Answer (score 3):

You represent negative binary literals with a negative sign, like this:

```
>>> -0b1010111
-87
```

Python's integers are not fixed width, so there is no "two's complement" as such.

Comment: Thanks! Um, how would I tell python to negatate 0b10101111?

Comment: Use the `-` unary operator. So `a = 0b10101111; print(a, -a)`

Comment: Sure, Python actually [*defines* the `~` operator in terms of unary `-`](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations): "The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its plain or long integer argument. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`. It only applies to integral numbers."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package. This package implements `TwosComplement` with binary integers and binary fractions. You can convert binary-fraction strings into their twos complement and vice-versa

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import TwosComplement, Binary
>>> int(Binary("01001011"))
75
>>> int(Binary("10101001"))
169
>>> TwosComplement("10101001").to_float()
-87.0
```

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.